# Exception handling in spring intergration router

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm newbie in integration. I have a router. In a specific scenario, the method  throws an exception. Based on that exception, how I can route my message.I want to catch that exception and based on route my message to another for example channel.

```
<integration:router ref="serviceImpl" method="getName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below:

First you configure the router and bean in the following manner:

```
<integration:router ref="serviceImpl" method="getName"/>
<beans:bean class="com.test.ServiceImpl" id="serviceImpl">
</beans:bean>
</int:router>
```

Then your `ServiceImpl.java` should be something like below:

```
 public class ServiceImpl {

     public String getName(Name name) {

      String channel = "";

      try {
       //Your business validations should be here and if everything is okay, then route the message to some channel
       channel = "goToSomeChannel"
      } catch (SomeException e) {
       //You got the exception, So route to different channel
       channel = "goToSomethingElseChannel";
      }

      return channel;
     }


}
```

In the end you define both the channels `goToSomeChannel` and `goToSomethingElseChannel` in your spring integration configuration file.